# How to highlight word in a string using coordinates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a problem to highlight multiple words in a sentence. I have text data like:

```
"The furnishing of Ci Suo 's home astonished the visitors: a home of 5 earthen and wooden structures, it has a sitting room with two layers of glass as well as a warehouse filled with mutton and ghee ."
```

and an array of an object:

```js
entities: [
      {
        "entity_type": "PERSON",
        "index": [
          18,
          26
        ],
        "namedEntity": "Ci Suo 's"
      },
      {
        "entity_type": "CARDINAL",
        "index": [
          69,
          69
        ],
        "namedEntity": "5"
      },
      {
        "entity_type": "CARDINAL",
        "index": [
          130,
          132
        ],
        "namedEntity": "two"
      }
    ]
```

I need to highlight it like this:
[image]

and this is what i tried so far:

```js
const find = entities; // word to highlight
let str = text; // contain the text i want  to highlight

for (let i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(find[i], "g"), match => {
    const color = randomColor();
    return `<span style="background: ${color}">${match}</span>`;
  });
}
```

with this approach I got some bugs like

- the later  tags can be matched in the next iteration if I have a word like "an"
- two same words get the same label

if you have another method can help, thanks

Comment: new RegExp(find[i].namedEntity, "g") should work, but i cant get why you search it again if you already have indexes

Comment: Try wrapping the phrase to find in word-boundaries, eg `new RegExp(\`\\b${find[i].namedEntity}\\b\`, 'g')`. That should help you with problem #1

Comment: @DmitryReutov yeah i think so. but later if i wrap one word with <span> the length of the sentence will get longer and the indexes wont be valid anymore

Answer (score 0):

As @Phill commented above you can add word-boundaries (e.g. `\b`) to the word that needs to be found, this should help.
Try this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
   const findRegExp = new RegExp("\\b" + find[i].namedEntity + "\\b","g");
   str = str.replace(findRegExp, function (match, index, wholeStr) {
        const color = randomColor();
        return `<span style="background: ${color}">${match}</span>`;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have all the information available in your entities array to replace the text from original one. You can use following.

```js
var text = "The furnishing of Ci Suo 's home astonished the visitors : a home of 5 earthen and wooden structures , it has a sitting room with two layers of glass as well as a warehouse filled with mutton and ghee ."
var entities = [
      {
        "entity_type": "PERSON",
        "index": [
          18,
          26
        ],
        "namedEntity": "Ci Suo 's"
      },
      {
        "entity_type": "CARDINAL",
        "index": [
          69,
          69
        ],
        "namedEntity": "5"
      },
      {
        "entity_type": "CARDINAL",
        "index": [
          130,
          132
        ],
        "namedEntity": "two"
      }
    ]


function buildText(text, entities) {
  var newText = text;
  
  entities.forEach(({entity_type, namedEntity, index}) => {
    newText = newText.replace(namedEntity, `<span class=${entity_type.toLowerCase()}>${namedEntity}</span>`)
  } )
  
  return newText;
}

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = buildText(text, entities);
```

```css
.person {
  background-color: red;
}

.cardinal {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id='content' />
```